# Windows Media Center Codecs

Tags: windows-media-center, codec, playback

I like Windows Media Center but I find the codecs limited for it and when I install a codec for Windows Media Player, Windows Media Center doesn't seem to pick it up. So my question is: how do I install codecs for Windows Media Center?

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Vista or 7 Media Centre then you need 2 things:

[Media Control](http://damienbt.free.fr/) and [FFDShow Tryouts](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout)

Full details on the Media Control page.

Read the [Configuration Guide](http://damienbt.free.fr/Information.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and easiest way is as follows:

1. Install [Shark007 codec pack](http://shark007.net/) and then select the "Shark recommended settings". This gets you all the codecs you need and configured correctly to work with W7MC.
2. Install and configure [MediaBrowser](http://www.mediabrowser.tv) which allows you to browse your TV shows and movie files that aren't typically shown in W7MC (mainly because they don't use Microsoft codecs).
3. Install [Media Control](http://damienbt.free.fr/) to enable FFWD and RWD when playing back these non-Microsoft codecs.

It shouldn't take you any more than about 30 minutes to get up and running.

Answer (score -1):

DirectShow codecs are usually loaded by the graph builder also under Windows Media Center.

However you can have troubles on 64 bit machines: Windows Media Player is by default the 32 bit version, so the codecs you'll see working there are not the same as in Media Center, that is always at 64 bit. In this case, you just have to install 64 bit codecs as well.